# Eclipse right-click issue with X11 forwarding

Tags: eclipse, gtk, x11, vnc, xserver

I have installed Eclipse on a remote Linux machine and trying to access it from my Windows box thru X11 forwarding. Yes, we have a requirement to do so.

I'm having a problem with right click behavior when using Eclipse (Helios/Indigo/Juno).  When I right click in Eclipse the popup menu briefly appears and then whatever menu item the cursor is near gets selected and that action is performed.  If I hold the right click then the popup menu stays open and I can select any menu item.  When I release the right click the selected menu item action is performed.  Note that in all of these cases the left mouse button is never used.

Tried different Linux flavors(SuSE/Ubuntu) and different X11 servers(Xming/Cygwin/VNC) for windows, the result is same. This happens only with Eclipse, other applications like firefox do not have this problem.

This behavior can partly be attributed to the way Linux handles mouse clicks i.e., releasing the right mouse button will trigger a selection.

Note that in all cases, Eclipse works without any problems locally(on the local Linux machine), these problems only appear when we access Eclipse remotely(X11/VNC) from a Windows box.

I am not sure if the problem is in Eclipse, because Eclipse works fine locally. Then, I am not sure if the problem is in X-server, because other applications like firefox works fine remotely.

Any ideas? Spending hell lot of time on this...!

Here are few related links:

http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5246614

http://communities.vmware.com/thread/220037

https://superuser.com/questions/433314/how-do-avoid-context-menu-in-opensuse-to-open-on-mousepress

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=542841

https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/947

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question but it has just started happening to me today (Nov 2016).

Macbook Pro Retina mid 2012 running Sierra with external mac monitor and touchpad
xquartz 2.7.11

using remote x to a redhat 7.2 machine running eclipse Mars (4.5.2)

This has worked consistently for years but after the upgrade to Sierra my right click (two finger tap on tracpad) on remote x running Eclipse causes the right click context menu to flash briefly and then goes away.

I noticed that I had both wireless and my lan connection active (just came back from a meeting and put mac on the monitors)

Found a couple of solutions - 
1. changing the two finger tap to a click on the lower right of the touch pad works (but I hate that) 
2. if I disable wireless to ensure all remote x sessions are on the cat5 my right click menu works again (two finger tap on trackpad) . I have consistently reproduced this a couple of days in a row now. 
3. use a mouse instead of the trackpad.